# What is the TensorFlow/Keras equivalent of PyTorch's `no_grad` function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

When writing machine learning models, I find myself needing to compute metrics, or run additional forward-passes in callbacks for visualization purposes. In **PyTorch**, I do this with [`torch.no_grad()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html?highlight=no_grad#torch.no_grad), and this prevents gradients from being computed and these operations, therefore, do not influence the optimization.

1. How does this mechanism work in **TensorFlow/Keras**?
2. **Keras** models are callable. So, something like `model(x)` is possible. But, it is also possible to say `model.predict(x)`, which also seems to invoke the `call`. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: [`tf.stop_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient)

Comment: also see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/advanced_autodiff

Answer (score 6):

The tensorflow equivalent would be [`tf.stop_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient)

Also don't forget, that Keras does not compute gradients when using predict (or just calling the model via `__call__`).

Comment: Is there a difference between calling via `__call__` and using `.predict`?